# Can we reformat the link/url structure using PHP?

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

How can we reformat the link structure from  http://mysite.com/my_page/6 to http://mysite.com/my_page/LittleThings using PHP??

Answer (score 0):

No,

Because it's a server-side problem. Server determines request, parse it and decide which php file should be executed. So if you want to forward a request to other file, you have to do this with server setups. FOr example you can do this with *.htaccess* file.

There are some examples : [http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F#all/-instructions--](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file?#all/-instructions--)